# execute generic methods via concurrent queue in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I want to execute some actions in background thread. However, the signature of methods that I want to execute in my background worker are not the same. For example:

```
objA.method1(arg1)
objA.method2(arg2)
objB.method3(arg3)
objA.method4(arg4)
```

Is it possible to use ConcurrentQueue or another class in such a way that allows me to specify the object, the method, and the arguments to the method, that I want to delegate to my worker thread?

I want to use something similar to ConcurrentQueue that will allow me to use producer-consumer pattern to generate and consume work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an anonymous method:

```
 Queue<Action> Q;

 Q.Enqueue(()=> objA.method1(arg1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a plenty of alternatives to `BackgroundWorker`, but you indeed can do anything with it too. Once I did this through a `static` method like this:

```
static BackgroundWorker StartWorker(DoWorkEventHandler _doWork,
                                    ProgressChangedEventHandler _progressChanged,
                                    RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler _runWorkerCompleted,
                                    bool _workerReportsProgress,
                                    bool _workerSupportsCancellation,
                                    object arg)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.WorkerReportsProgress = _workerReportsProgress;
    worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = _workerSupportsCancellation;
    worker.DoWork += _doWork;
    worker.ProgressChanged += _progressChanged;
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += _runWorkerCompleted;
    try
    {
        worker.RunWorkerAsync(arg);
        return worker;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //...
        return null;
    }
}
```

So you can pass here any delegates through lambda, if methods' bodies are rather small:

```
StartWorker((s, e) =>
    {
        object argument = e.Argument;
        //do any work you need
    },
    (s, e) =>
    {
        //do smth on progress changed
    },
    (s, e) =>
    {
        //do smth on worker completed
    },
    true,
    true,
    null);//pass any argument you need
```

Or you can use explicitly written methods...

Surely you can omit any of the `ProgressChangedEventHandler` and `RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler` if you needn't them.

Comment: Thanks. But I need something close to a concurrentQueue solution as I do not want to start new threads for each new task